# Kotlin basics: how to add or set an element of a Map?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, mutablemap

I'd like to add/set elements of a mutable map with specific key-value pairs.
So far, I figured out that I can can add new elements using the plus operator along with the Pair data type:

```
var arr3:Map<Any, Any> = mutableMapOf()
arr3 += Pair("manufacturer", "Weyland-Yutani")
//also, the "to" operator works too:
//arr3 += ("manufacturer" to "Weyland-Yutani")
```

However, I couldn't find out how to modify or add new key-value pairs:

```
arr3["manufacturer"] = "Seegson"  // gives an error( Kotlin: No set method providing array access)
arr3["manufacturer"] to "Seegson" // compiles, but nothing is added to the array
```

Could you please elaborate me how to do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You've declared mutable `arr3` with explicit type of `Map<Any, Any>`. The [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/)) interface allows no mutation. The `+=` operator creates a new instance of map and mutates the variable `arr3`. To modify contents of the map declare the `arr3` as [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/) like so:

```
var arr3:MutableMap<Any, Any> = mutableMapOf()
```

or more idiomatic

```
var arr = mutableMapOf<Any, Any>()
```

Note that typically you need either mutable variable `var` or mutable instance type `MutableMap` but from my experience rarely both.

In other words you could use mutable variable with immutable type:

```
var arr = mapOf<Any,Any>()
```

and use `+=` operator to modify *where* `arr` points to.

Or you could use `MutableMap` with immutable `arr` variable and modify contents of where `arr` points to:

```
val arr = mutableMapOf<Any,Any>()
```

Obviously you can only modify `MutableMap` contents. So `arr["manufacturer"] = "Seegson"` will only work with a variable which is declared as such.

Comment: **"The += operator creates a new instance of map and mutates the variable arr3"** Dang it, that behavior tricked me (the wrong type was my fault). Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 20):

Regarding the add/set operations, these can be performed on the `MutableMap<K, V>` (not just `Map<K, V>`) and can be done in several ways:

- The Java-style `put` call:

  ```
  arr3.put("manufacturer", "Seegson")
  ```

  This call returns the value that was previously associated with the key, or `null`.
- A more idiomatic Kotlin call using the [`set` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations):

  ```
  arr["matufacturer"] = "Seegson"
  ```
- The `plusAssign` operator syntax:

  ```
  arr += "manufacturer" to "Seegson"
  ```

  This option introduces overhead of a `Pair` created before the call and is less readable because it can be confused with a `var` reassignment (also, it is not applicable for `var`s because of ambiguity), but still is useful when you already have a `Pair` that you want to add.